# Have I found a bug in gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm building an application that uses gstreamer as a media back end. I think i may have isolated a bug in gstreamer. Is this the case or am i doing something wrong?

If i decode, and then immediately encode, a jpeg image using this:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=../front_thumbnail_1976.jpg ! jpegdec ! colorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv,format='(fourcc)'UYVY,width=2592,height=1936,framerate='(fraction)'0/1 ! jpegenc ! filesink location=sample.jpeg
```

everything works. However, if i try to split up the pipeline, with an intermediate file, like this:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=../front_thumbnail_1976.jpg ! jpegdec ! colorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv,format='(fourcc)'UYVY,width=2592,height=1936,framerate='(fraction)'0/1 ! filesink location=sample.yuv

gst-launch filesrc location=sample.yuv ! video/x-raw-yuv,format='(fourcc)'UYVY,width=2592,height=1936,framerate='(fraction)'0/1 ! jpegenc ! filesink location=sample.jpeg
```

I get a segfault (on the second line). Have i missed a step? or is something wrong with gstreamer? I can provide my sample data if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a segfault chances are that you indeed found a bug. File a bugreport on http://bugzilla.gnome.org. Also do:

```
gdb --args gst-launch filesrc location=sample.yuv ! video/x-raw-yuv,format='(fourcc)'UYVY,width=2592,height=1936,framerate='(fraction)'0/1 ! jpegenc ! filesink location=sample.jpeg
```

inside gdb type 'r' for run and upon the crash type 'bt' to get a backtrace. Make sure you have debug packages fpr gstreamer/glib/libjpeg installed. Attach the backtrace to the bugreport.